# while loop with exception handling

Tags: java, while-loop, exception, try-catch, throw

This is my first time using exception handling so be gentle. I have a simple blob class that accepts an ID, the id must be between 30 and 50 or else an exception is thrown.

```
public class Blob {
int id;

public Blob() {

}

public Blob(int id) throws Exception {
    this.id = id;
    if (id < 30 || id > 50)
        throw new Exception ("id = " +id+ ", must be between 30 and 50 inclusive");
}
}
```

It should prompt the user to enter an id, and throw the exception if it's not between 30 and 50, and should continue until the user enters a valid input and then simply displays the id number.

```
public class BlobCreator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int id;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter ID number: ");
    id = scan.nextInt();

    do {
        try {
            Blob b = new Blob(id);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Enter a different ID: ");
        id = scan.nextInt();
    }
    while(true);
    }   
System.out.println("Blob ID: " +id);
}
```

I think that I am using the throw and catch correctly, but my loop isn't working correctly so I think that should be a simple fix but I can't get it just right. Also is using a while loop like I have the best way for this situation or is there a better way to loop through throw and catch?

Thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should place the `break;` after the code is executed successfully.

```
do {
    try {
        Blob b = new Blob(id);
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    System.out.println("Enter a different ID: ");
    id = scan.nextInt();
} while(true);
```

So each time the loop would reach the end of its body, it would break out of the loop. You only should break after the `blob` is created successfully. Although I dont see why you put a `break` anyway. The `while` loop can check if the entered input was valid and simply stop the loop.

I modified the `while` in a `do-while` loop... By using `true` the loop will run forever, unless no exception is thrown by the constructor... This makes the code more generic (if you modify the conditions of the blob-construction, you don't have to modify the condition of the `while` loop).

Comment: Yes same problem when I do it this way.

Comment: even if break is deleted still continuously runs never getting out of the loop

Comment: No you should introduce a break after the construction of the blob, Third modification.... and add an scan for a next integer. This code at least should ask you to insert a new integer... Before going for another run... And you better use a do-while, otherwise one should not create a blob when the `id` was correct in the fist place.

Comment: I updated the code, seems to be working right. Notice any flaws?

Comment: Yeah: if you enter the `id` correct the first time, your code will not execute the `while` body and thus no blob will be created. Therefore I modified the `while` in a `do-while` loop... By using `true` the loop will run forever, unless no exception is thrown by the constructor... This makes the code more generic (if you modify the conditions of the blob-construction, you don't have to modify the condition of the `while` loop).

Comment: Ok thanks, when I use with do-while it says that my System.out.println is unreachable, any ideas?

Comment: Which one? The one in the catch block or the one at the bottom. They should be reachable...

Comment: The one at the bottom, but I fixed that problem it is reachable but I'm still getting a (Syntax error on token, "println", = expected after this token)???

Comment: Could you post the entire code (in your question)... In Java the posted code appears to run on my machine :S.

Comment: I updated code to how I have it now, all is good except for the println

Comment: You close a bracket below the while. This bracket then marks the end of the method. And you can't write a statement in the class part. You need to remove that bracket, then it will work (hopefully :))

Comment: Ha that's the bracket I put to fix my unreachable problem, if I delete it then the println goes to "unreachable".

Comment: You should put a break below the constructor `Blob b = new Blob(id);`, does that resolve the problem (the `break` should be there anyway...)

Comment: Indeed that fixed my problem, Thanks for all your help you were very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, its kind of late to the party. Hope users who endup here may find this useful.
 The use of `break` keyword is discouraged 
Here is a very simple implementation to break away after implementing a retry mechanism
This iterates over the loop for the specified number of times and also if the exception still persists, then the exception is thrown. This can be leveraged for an actual real world scenario where the `resttemplate` might actually result in IO/Network errors and can be retried in those cases

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {
            int c = anotherM();
            System.out.println("Now the value is" + c);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Inside" + e);
        }
    }

    public static int anotherM() throws Exception {
        int i = 4;
        Exception ex = null;
        while (i > 0) {
            try {
                System.out.println("print i" + i);

                throw new IOException();
                // return i;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);

                i--;
                if (i == 1) {
                    ex = new Exception("ttt");

                }

            }
        }
        if (ex != null) {
            throw new Exception("all new");
        } else {
            return i;
        }

    }

}
```